# What is the duration of a pre_acknowledge message?

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

When I configure messages to PRE_ACKNOWLEDGE when heading to an array of consumers, do they get removed from the address space immediately or do they hang around for any other reason? I have a client that is misbehaving and locking up. It is not responding with acknowledgements, of course. It is set to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE right now.

I'm using JBoss 7.1.3, HornetQ 2.2.21.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRE-ACKs will set the message to be removed as soon as Netty delivers it to the client.

It seems you're facing https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1125042

Comment: It seems I don't have access to that issue. I suppose it comes down to what the definition of "delivered" is. If there is a successful return on the send or other state? We are seeing messages getting stuck in the TCP pipe and are never being acknowledge which hangs the server because topic messages pile up in the address space. PAGING, etc. doesn't help for messages that will never be written to a hung client. If there is a nuance about the linked issue that I am missing, please advise and thanks for the reply.